# Tkinter Window: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I'm having trouble solving the Concatenate Error when it's present in a Tkinter Window. I tried using multiple methods but, they didn't work to well with what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make it so where, at the click of a Tkinter button, it would randomly choose a value between 0 and 100. If the random value is less than or equal to 70, both "Good Guy" and "Bad Guy" would have their health reduced. But if it's greater than 70, Good guy would only take damage. It would then print their new hp into the window.

```
from random import randrange


class App5(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)

        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.theme_use("classic")
        self.geometry("490x250")

        self.tres_label = ttk.Label(
            self,
            text="Oh yeah, also while you were doing that, I enrolled you into a tournament. \nHave fun........what? Why did I sign you up for a tournament you didn't ask for? \nTo increase the total run time on this project.",
        )
        self.tres_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.rng_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Click Me", command=self.rng)
        self.rng_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    def rng(self):
        class Character:
            def __init__(self, name: str, hp: int, damage: int):
                self.name = name
                self.hp = hp
                self.damage = damage

        Goodguy = Character("Goodguy", 300, 75)
        Badguy = Character("Badguy", 375, 25)
        score = 70
        num = randrange(0, 100)
        G = Goodguy.hp - Badguy.damage
        B = Badguy.hp - Goodguy.damage

        if num >= score:
            Goodguy.hp - Badguy.damage
            Badguy.hp - Goodguy.damage
            self.good = ttk.Label(self, text="Goodguy Hp:" + G)
            self.good.grid(row=3, column=3)
            self.bad = ttk.Label(self, text="BadGuy Hp:" + B)
            self.bad.grid(row=3, column=6)
            B = B - Goodguy.damage
            G = G - Badguy.damage
        else:
            Goodguy.hp - Badguy.damage
            self.good = ttk.Label(self, text="Goodguy Hp:" + G)
            self.good.grid(row=3, column=3)
            self.bad = ttk.Label(self, text="BadGuy Hp:" + B)
            self.bad.grid(row=3, column=6)
            B = B - Goodguy.damage
            G = G - Badguy.damage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suspect the issue is here:

```
self.good = ttk.Label(self, text="Goodguy Hp:" + G)
```

what type is G? if it's an `int` you cannot add them together like you're trying to do, you need to change it to `text="Goodguy Hp: " + str(G)`, or use an f-string like @AKX mentioned

try changing this expression in all four places

Answer (score 2):

> can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

is telling you exactly what the error is (and the traceback, which you should have added into your original question anyway, would have pinpointed exactly where).

The issue is you can't "sum up" a string and an integer. Instead, use string formatting:

```
"Goodguy Hp:" + G
```

would become

```
f"Goodguy Hp:{G}"
```

using [f-string formatting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-f-strings-literal-string-interpolation).

The same stands for the other good guy and bad guy labels.

Answer (score 0):

In python you cannot concatenate an integer and a string. If you do try to do that it would result in the following error which you have gotten:

```
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

The issues would be in the following blocks of code:

```py
"Goodguy Hp:" + G
```

and

```py
"BadGuy Hp:" + B
```

To solve this issue,
You could use the solutions @AKX and @vencaslac provided or you could use the %d operator:

```py
"Goodguy Hp: %d" % G
```

```py
"Badguy Hp: %d" % B
```